# Converting from std::vector<> to a double pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, stdvector

I was wondering out of curiosity if it is possible to cast a std::vector<> to a double pointer.

I've never had an issue passing a std::vector as a pointer in this fashion:

```
std::vector<char> myCharVector;
myCharVector.push_back('a');
myCharVector.push_back('b');
myCharVector.push_back('c');
char *myCharPointer = &myCharVector[0];
```

So I was curious if it was possible to assign the address of the pointer in a similar way to this:

```
char *myPointer = "abc";
char **myDoublePointer = &myPointer;
```

I've tried:

```
char **myDoublePointer = (char**)&myCharVector;
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Is this for anything more than curiosity?

Comment: What error do you get for this line: `char **myDoublePointer = (char**)&myCharVector;` ?

Comment: @weidi there is no error

Comment: @Pondwater Then what doesn't work as you said it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already know that `&myCharVector[0]` is a pointer to `char`.  So if you store it in a variable:

```
char *cstr = &myCharVector[0];
```

then you can take the address of that variable:

```
char **ptrToCstr = &cstr;
```

But simply dereferencing twice like this:

```
char **ptrToCstr = &(&myCharVector[0])
```

is invalid because the value `(&myCharVector[0])` isn't stored in memory anywhere yet.

Comment: Well it's certainly in memory, but it's an rvalue so taking its address is disallowed as a safety precaution.

Comment: Not necessarily, it might be in a register.

Comment: Fair enough. To clarify my comment, it's not hard to have the compiler allocate temporary stack space for the temporary to allow its address to be taken. For example, given `char*& to_lvalue(char*&& x) { return x; }`, you could write `char** ptrToCstr = &to_lvalue(&myCharVector[0])`, but the pointer would be unusable after the statement, which is what I meant was the safety precaution.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, you can do:

```
char *myCharPointer = myCharVector.data();
```

But you cannot take the address of the return value of `data()` because it does not return a reference to the underlying storage, just the pointer value.

If the purpose is to be able to change what the pointer is pointing to, then you may really want a pointer to a vector, rather than a pointer to a pointer to a char. But, the `STL` doesn't let you change the underlying pointer within the vector itself without going through the regular vector APIs (like `resize` or `swap`).

Answer (score 3):

You most definitely **can't** do this. `std::vector` and a `char **` are completely different types of objects and you can't just "cast" one to another.

The reason you were able to do `char *myCharPointer = &myCharVector[0]` is that `myCharVector[0]` gives you a `char`, and thus `&myCharVector[0]` gives you the address of that `char`, which you can assign to a `char *`.

The only way you could convert a full `std::vector` into a `char *` (not `char **`) is to loop over your `std::vector` and construct a `char *` from the data manually.

For instance something like:

```
char *ptr = malloc(myCharVector.size()+1);
for (unsigned int i=0; i < myCharVector.size(); i++) {
  ptr[i] = myCharVector[i];
}
ptr[myCharVector.size()] = 0;
```

Then `ptr` will be a C string of `char`s.

Comment: @BenVoigt, what do you mean? The part about converting to a `char *`?

Comment: The part about needing to make a copy of the vector in order to get a contiguous block (so that pointer subscripting works) is wrong.  `vector` contents are guaranteed to be stored contiguously, so that `&v[i] == i + &v[0]`

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, but that only works as long as the vector doesn't get modified, correct?

Comment: You do have to be careful about anything that invalidates iterators.  Not all modifications do (Replacing elements, or removing elements, won't be a problem.  Inserting will, unless you reserved space in advance.)